# Looping an object(stdClass)#1

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["trackingNo"]=>
  array(18) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "
888005324912

"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "
1900530244582

"
    [2]=>
    string(15) "
778180519352

"
    [3]=>
    string(16) "
1000237325384

"
```

How do i loop through a data like this? When i do a var_dump on this $obj , it returns the data above but when i do a echo `$obj`, i get nothing. Any idea why is that so too?

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Comment: You should get an error if you enable error reporting (add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the very top of your script).

Comment: @AmalMurali Thank you so much for this advice, very useful for debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object contains an array, do it like this.

```
foreach($obj->trackingNo as $trackingNo){
    echo $trackingNo."\n";
    /*Or whatever you want to do with $trackingNo.*/
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify , $obj-> the arrow represents for each item IN trackingNo ?

Comment: The arrow represents going down in the object. The foreach is each item in the array `trackingNo`.